# Magento2 - How to add custom login/register step on the checkout

Tags: magento, knockout.js, magento2, checkout

I wish to add a custom login register step step on the checkout. This step should be visible only to the non-logged-in users. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a custom module in order to achieve this functionality. Refer the below link from the documentation :

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_step.html

Also it is already answered at this stackexchange link :

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/169969/magento2-add-login-form-in-checkout-page